# Difference between plain function and function returning multiple functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I don't understand the difference between the two statements below.  Why does returning a function twice in the logger make it any different ?

## RETURN FUNCTIONS

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
    let result
    console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type)
    console.log('prev state', store.getState())
    console.log('action', action)
    result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.groupEnd()
    return result
}
```

## DON'T RETURN FUNCTIONS

```
const logger = (store, next, action) => {
    let result
    console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type)
    console.log('prev state', store.getState())
    console.log('action', action)
    result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.groupEnd()
    return result
}
```

Comment: well, it's all about closures, you can then pass a function that already knows the `store` and the `next` function in the first scenario, and only `action` would be variable. In the second function, none of the arguments are fixed and can be less optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so you can partially apply parameters to the function. For example, you may only know (or have in scope) your `store` and `next` function at a particular point in time. Later on, during execution, you may then have your `action` parameter but the `store` is out of scope.

Therefore, you partially apply the first two parameters and then pass the returned function around so it can finally be executed with the third parameter at a later stage. When it is finally executed with the third parameter it has access to the first two parameters because they were enclosed in the partially applied function. An example might clarify:

```
 const store = {
    getState: () => 'foo'
}
// this can be passed around, it creates a closure around store so will have access to it later
const partialLogger = logger(store)((ac) => ({
    ac,
    bar: 2
}));
// some time later - execute
const res = partialLogger({ type: 'baz' });
console.log('>res', res);
```

Comment: Excellent !  I understood the closure aspect of the logger function but this helps to connect the dots.